# How to do one Result Activity for a various of Classes

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I would like to do a result Activity where i can store the results of various classes/Activities of my Quiz game. So for exmaple the score result of Lvl 1, Lvl 2 and Lvl 3 is supposed to be shown at one result Activity.

Right now this is my shorted Code for Lvl1.java and Lvl2.java:

Lvl1.java:

```
trueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if (updateMyQuestAndAnsw == Questions.QuestionsKlasse1.length){

                                Intent iresultActivity = new Intent(Class1.this, ResultClass.class);

                                iresultActivity.putExtra("finaleScore",updateMyScoreTextView );
                                Class1.this.finish();
                                startActivity(iresultActivity);
```

Lvl2.java:

```
trueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (updateMyQuestAndAnsw == Questions.QuestionsKlasse2.length){

                                    Intent iresultActivity = new Intent(Class2.this, ResultClass.class);

                                    iresultActivity.putExtra("finaleScore2",updateMyScoreTextView );
                                    Class2.this.finish();
                                    startActivity(iresultActivity);
```

Now this is my ResultActivity.java where the result of the game is supposed to be shown:

```
////////////Result of Lvl 1
    final int score = getIntent().getIntExtra("finaleScore", 0);

        punkteanzahl.setText("You gained " + score + " out of " + Questions.QuestionsKlasse1.length + " points");

    if (score <= 15 && score >= 12) {
        note.setText("Note: 1 - Very good");
        bestanden.setText("Text Text!");

    } else if (score <= 12 && score >= 9) {
        note.setText("Note: 2 - Good");
        bestanden.setText("Text Text...!");

    } else if (score <= 9 && score >= 5) {
        note.setText("Note: 3 - It´s ok!");
        bestanden.setText("Text.....!");

    } else if (score <= 4 && score >= 3) {
        note.setText("Note: 4 - Not so good");
        bestanden.setText("Text--...!");

    } else if (score < 3) {
        note.setText("Note: 5 - Very Bad");
        bestanden.setText("Text.....!");

    }

    ////////////Result of Lvl 2
    final int score2 = getIntent().getIntExtra("finaleScore2", 0);

        punkteanzahl.setText("You gained " + score2 + " out of " + Questions.QuestionsKlasse2.length + " points");

    if (score2 <= 15 && score2 >= 12) {
        note.setText("Note: 1 - Very good");
        bestanden.setText("Text Text!");
    } else if (score2 <= 12 && score2 >= 9) {
        note.setText("Note: 2 - Good");
        bestanden.setText("Text Text!");
    } else if (score2 <= 9 && score2 >= 5) {
        note.setText("Note: 3 - It´s ok");
        bestanden.setText("Text Text!!");
    } else if (score2 <= 4 && score2 >= 3) {
        note.setText("Note: 4 - Not so good");
        bestanden.setText("Text Text!!");
    } else if (score2 < 3) {
        note.setText("Note: 5 - Very Bad");
        bestanden.setText("Text Text!!");
    }
```

The Problem is, if i am finsihed with Lvl 1 it won´t show me the result of Lvl 1.java. It always says that i have reached 0 points. Instead if i play Lvl2 it shows me the correct result.  Or do i have to do one resultActivity.java for every Lvl.java? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Problem is, if i am finsihed with Lvl 1 it won´t show me the result of Lvl 1.java. It always says that i have reached 0 points. Instead if i play Lvl2 it shows me the correct result.

Good problem, but, this is how the code is written. Keep in mind that java/kotlin is compiled from top to bottom. Thus, your code will set the text for **punkteanzahl** twice.

> do i have to do one resultActivity.java for every Lvl.java

No, actually, using only one result activity is a good thing. And, you could do that with the lvl also. But, i dont suggest that you dig in there yet.

I noticed that you are a beginner and, most probably have not that much knowledge on java. Might i suggest you start on the basic first :)

**TL;DR**

Set the default values from ***getIntExtra*** to -1 then check if the score is not -1 before setting it to the text, example:

```
final int score = getIntent().getIntExtra("finaleScore", -1);
if (score != -1) punkteanzahl.setText("You gained " + score + " out of " + Questions.QuestionsKlasse1.length + " points");
```

**Suggestion**

I'll share one nifty trick you could do, just use one key for the final score. Then use this to pass all the scores from different levels. This way you have less code on ResultActivity.java and, it would still work.

Comment: Hey @Jian , sorry for the late answer. Your Suggestion worked perfect for me :). Im kind of new to java and programming in general. Thanks, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever read about fragments?
I'm making something too and I'll use those, the'll load on the same activitie:
Info:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?gclid=Cj0KCQjwn4ncBRCaARIsAFD5-gWOjoEJj6UIEFZQXsOMQfMNDqb4dzrVstCsRohbVJ-7lPHzOBJTHhAaArrTEALw_wcB

Comment: Please could you explain how the asker could use fragments to solve their problem?

Comment: @Adi Bradfield and Otávio. Thanks for the hint. Im new to java programming but if this may the solution i will read into it.

Comment: He could use the fragments as he is using the activities, (familiar to him), but it would be more efficient.